# Demon Slayer (Kimetsu No Yaiba) Dubbed version...can't quite catch

Tags: demon-slayer

I am non-native English speaker trying to practice my listening skill by watching and listening my favorite anime Kimetsu no yaiba English dubbed version.
(I have found that this way I tend to keep my focus longer with interest)

I have watched the first episode and am stuck at the first encounter of Tanjiro and Giyu Tomioka.

When Tanjiro begged not to kill Nezuko, Giyu got angry and said,
"Don't xxxxxxx like that will give your enemy the chance to kill you!"
I couldn't catch the xxxxxxx part at all, and can not find any closed caption.
English Subtitles of Japanese audio doesn't match with dubbed version so I am totally lost.
I tried to guess and the closest word I could get was "quave" or "grovel",
If you watched the English Dub, would you please teach me what it says?
In original word in Japanese was, "Seisatsu Yodatsu No Ken Wo Tanin Ni Nigiraseruna! (生殺与奪の権を他人に握らせるな）"

Thank you for your help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You heard correctly, the line is "Don't **grovel** like that and give your enemies the chance to kill you!". Grovel meaning "to lie or creep with the body prostrate in token of subservience or abasement" which refers to Tanjiro kowtowing in front of Giyu, pitifully begging him not to kill his sister. Its an interesting translation, the subtitle of the line in the sub ("Don't ever give others a chance to murder you") is a decently direct translation of the spoken line ("生殺与奪の権を他人に握らせるな") and makes no mention of Tanjiro's posture.